# Swift Generics: How to avoid this strange behaviour?

Tags: swift, generics

I met with the strange behaviour. Maybe i'm doing it wrong but I have not a clue.

Error: **`Cannot assign value of type '[Itemable]' to type '[T]'`**

```
protocol Itemable {
    var id: Int { get set }
}

protocol Paginatable {
    var items: [Itemable] { get set }
}

class Fetcher<T: Itemable, P: Paginatable> {
    var items = [T]()
    
    func onReceive(pagination: P) {
        items = pagination.items
    }
}
```

Comment: `pagination.items` is a `[Itemable]`. `self.items` has type `[T]`, which *could* be `[Itemable]` when `T` is `Itemable`, but `T` could also be *any other subtype of the `Itemable` protocol, including other protocols that subtype Itemable, or conformers of `Itemable`.

Answer (score 2):

Class `Fetcher` expects a `T` type, i.e. a specific type conforming to `Itemable`.

So, for example, if you had a type `Foo: Itemable`, `Fetcher<Foo, ...>` would expect to work with `Foo`s - not any `Itemable`, like `AnotherFoo: Itemable` - but only `Foo`.

Yet `P`s don't have such as restriction on their `items` property - both `Foo` and `AnotherFoo` and something else could be in `items`.

So, you're basically trying to do the following:

```swift
let items: [Itemable] = [...]
let foos: [Foo] = items // error
```

---

If you want to constrain `P` to hold the same items as `T`, then you could do the following:

```
protocol Itemable {
    var id: Int { get set }
}

protocol Paginatable {
    associatedtype Item: Itemable
    var items: [Item] { get set }
}

class Fetcher<T, P: Paginatable> where P.Item == T {
    var items = [T]()

    func onReceive(pagination: P) {
        items = pagination.items
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need Paginatable to be a generic. Then everything falls into place. You do not want it to declare an array of Itemable but an array of some Itemable *adopter*. That is exactly what a generic lets you say.

---

In other words:

```
protocol Paginatable {
    var items: [Itemable] { get set }
}
```

...means: "Whoever adopts me (I'm looking at you, Fetcher), must *declare* that `items` is `[Itemable]`." That is not what you want Fetcher to have to say. But you are forcing Fetcher to say that.

Instead, say this:

```
protocol Paginatable {
    associatedtype T : Itemable
    var items: [T] { get set }
}
```

Now you are saying: "Whoever adopts me can declare `items` as an array of any type as long as that type adopts Itemable." That is exactly what you *do* want to say.

---

To illustrate further, this is illegal:

```
protocol Itemable { }
protocol Paginatable {
    var items: [Itemable] { get set }
}
struct Dummy : Itemable {}
struct Fetcher : Paginatable { // error
    var items: [Dummy]
}
```

But this is fine:

```
protocol Itemable { }
protocol Paginatable {
    associatedtype T : Itemable
    var items: [T] { get set }
}
struct Dummy : Itemable {}
struct Fetcher : Paginatable {
    var items: [Dummy]
}
```

And that second thing is exactly what you want to say. Now that you've understood that, if you *then* want to make Fetcher a generic too, no problem:

```
protocol Itemable { }
protocol Paginatable {
    associatedtype T : Itemable
    var items: [T] { get set }
}
struct Dummy : Itemable {}
struct Fetcher <T:Itemable> : Paginatable {
    var items: [T]
}
```